# command 'git add .' add the file I needn't when i created the gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

This is my .gitignore file content:

```
# Executables

[0-1][1-5]/my*
```

my git dir is:

```
    .
    |-- 01
    |   `-- more02.c
    |-- 02
    |   |-- cp01.c
    |   |-- tmp
    |   |-- tmp.cop
    |   |-- utmplib.h
    |   `-- who01.c
    |-- 03
    |   |-- ls01.c
    |   |-- ls02.c
    |   |-- myls
    |   |-- myls2
    |   `-- utility.h
    |-- 04
    |   |-- mypwd
    |   `-- spwd.c
    |-- 05
    |   |-- mystty
    |   `-- showtty.c
    |-- 06
    |   |-- myerror
    |   |-- myplayagain
    |   |-- myplayagain3
    |   |-- myplayagain5
    |   |-- mysignal
    |   |-- play_again3.c
    |   |-- play_again.c
    |   `-- signaldemo1.c
    |-- 07
    |   |-- hello2.c
    |   |-- hello3.c
    |   |-- myhello
    |   |-- myhello2
    |   |-- myticker1
    |   `-- ticker_demo1.c
    |-- LICENSE
    `-- README.md
```

I want exclude the file under dir [01] [02] ... start with my*, but when i use the command 
`git add .` , the file my* appears in the gitrepostory.

someone can tell me the reason?

Comment: I tested the same on my pc and its working fine.. check if the gitignore file itself is listed in ignore list in any of the gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

well, I have made an experiment that in this way, there is no problem with your method. So I think the reason may be other config of git to let the .gitignore file disable. Here I list my test process.
➜  perlexamples git:(test3) ✗ mkdir 02
➜  perlexamples git:(test3) ✗ vim .gitignore
add [0-1][1-5] to the gitignore file
➜  02 git:(test3) ✗ vim my.txt
➜  02 git:(test3) ✗ git st

## On branch test3

## Untracked files:

## (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

#

## ../20131026_craw_test.pl

1 ssdf

## ../hash_test.pl

## ../other_mech.pl

## ../rsp.txt

## ../words.pl

no my.txt file in the repository

➜  02 git:(test3) ✗ vim a.txtwq

➜  perlexamples git:(test3) ✗ git st

## On branch test3

## Untracked files:

## (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

#

## 02/

## 20131026_craw_test.pl

## hash_test.pl

## other_mech.pl

## rsp.txt

## words.pl

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

now 02/ is in the repository.

Comment: It's strange. anyway , I changed .gitignoe and add the `my*`, so it works